# Laravel 8: In Controller - how to get values array from model object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This should be simple, but I can't seem to find an answer.  Finally got it routing right, but now I can't get the row data from the table as an array.  How do I do that?

Route:

```
  Route::get('/view/{ability}',  [AbilityController::class, 'show'])->name('view');
```

Ability controller has this:

```
   public function show(Ability $ability)
   {
            var_dump($ability);
   }
```

How do I get the data from $ability as if I did a "SELECT * " and put it in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an eloquent model you can just call the [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-toarray) method to return the array. Try:

```php
   public function show(Ability $ability)
   {
            var_dump($ability->toArray());
   }
```

But, in most cases, the eloquent model is much more powerful once you learn how to use it.